multiple D/EGL_emulation on console in flutter
D/EGL_emulation(11951): app_time_stats: avg=501.44ms min=498.69ms max=504.19ms count=2
Above line is thrown by console infinitly when deals with TEXTFIELD Widget. How to remove this ?
I want to remove this infinitely throwing of that line of message.
